# Concatenate two rows into 1 oracle,

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

the data i have is as follows.

```
> ID    Somefield
  00001      test1
  00001s     test2
  00002      test3
  00002g     test4
```

I want to concatenate those two lines together based on the first five digits of the ID
end result would be

```
00001    test1,test2
00002    test3,test4
```

I am able to do this with the listagg function in 11g but i have to pass a where clause and look at the length of the ID field.

I tried to create a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION row_concat_id( id           IN VARCHAR2,
                                          currentfield IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS

  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT listagg(currentfield, ',') within GROUP(ORDER BY currentfield)    
      FROM mytable
     WHERE id LIKE (id + '%')
    --where length(ID) > 5
     GROUP BY subscriberid;

  concatfield VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN

  dbms_output.put_line(id);
  dbms_output.put_line(currentfield);

  OPEN c1;

  FETCH c1 INTO concatfield;

  CLOSE c1;

  RETURN concatfield;

END row_concat_id;
```

it will work only if i hard code the id into the function where clause

```
where id like(id + '%')
```

like so

```
where id like(00001%')
```

any help with this would be great.

Comment: How did you make `+` able to concatenate strings in Oracle 11g?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly confused here... You're using a cursor just to group by the id column?  Wouldn't something like this work for you?

```
SELECT substr(ID,0,5), listagg(somefield,',')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY substr(ID,0,5)
```

Obviously if you wanted this to be a function, you would need to prepare the SQL so that somefield would be a field name and not just a string.

To elaborate, your cursor would use something like

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT substr('||ID||',0,5), listagg('||somefield||','''','''')
     FROM mytable
     GROUP BY substr('||ID||',0,5)'
```

Comment: I was using the substr but did not duplicate it in the group by. I was doing an alias on the substr column in the select and grouping by that. this works thanks

Comment: While that works I have about 15 columns and they all need to be in the group by. What would be an alternative to the group by clause?

Comment: @JoeCook What do you mean?  It sounds like that might be a whole new question.  Why are you grouping by 15 different columns/why can't you just add them to your group by?

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your cursor to

```
select listagg(SUBSTR(currentField,1,5), ',') within group (order by        
   SUBSTR(currentField,1,5))
```